# Function won't follow through with the format inside of it

Tags: python, function, format, equation

So I have a code designed to calculate windchill at incremental speeds between 5 and 60, the user inputs the temperature and then inputs the measurement and depending on what they input the code will call either the Fahrenheit functions or the Celsius functions. The problem I'm having is the format in each function does not seem to be working. This is my code currently:

```
import math

t = float(input("What is the temperature?: "))
degree = input("Fahrenheit or celsius? Please put F or C: ")
wciC = 13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(5, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(5, 0.16)
wciF = 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(5, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(5, 0.16)

def fiveMileC(wciC, t):

    wciC = 13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(5, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(5, 0.16)
    print("At temperature [0].0C, and wind speed 5 mph, the windchill is: [1]".format(t, wciC))
    
    return fiveMileC

def fiveMileF(wciF, t):
    
    wciF = 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(5, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(5, 0.16)
    print("At temperature [0].0F, and wind speed 5 mph, the windchill is: [1]".format(t, wciF))
    
    return fiveMileF

def tenMileC(wciC, t):

    wciC = 13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(10, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(10, 0.16)
    
    return tenMileC

def tenMileF(wciF, t):
    
    wciF = 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(10, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(10, 0.16)
    print("At temperature [0].0F, and wind speed 10 mph, the windchill is: [1]".format(t, wciF))
    
    return tenMileF

def fifteenMileC(wciC, t):

    wciC = 13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(15, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(15, 0.16)
    
    return fifteenMileC

def fifteenMileF(wciF, t):
    
    wciF = 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(15, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(15, 0.16)
    print("At temperature [0].0F, and wind speed 15 mph, the windchill is: [1]".format(t, wciF))
    
    return fifteenMileF

def twentyMileC(wciC, t):

    wciC = 13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(20, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(20, 0.16)
    
    return twentyMileC

def twentyMileF(wciF, t):
    
    wciF = 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(20, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(20, 0.16)
    print("At temperature [0].0F, and wind speed 20 mph, the windchill is: [1]".format(t, wciF))
    
    return twentyMileF

def twentyFiveMileC(wciC, t):

    wciC = 13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(25, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(25, 0.16)
    
    return twentyFiveMileC

def twentyFiveMileF(wciF, t):
    
    wciF = 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(25, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(25, 0.16)
    print("At temperature [0].0F, and wind speed 25 mph, the windchill is: [1]".format(t, wciF))
    
    return twentyFiveMileF

def thirtyMileC(wciC, t):

    wciC = 13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(30, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(30, 0.16)
    
    return thirtyMileC

def thirtyMileF(wciF, t):
    
    wciF = 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(30, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(30, 0.16)
    print("At temperature [0].0F, and wind speed 30 mph, the windchill is: [1]".format(t, wciF))
    
    return thirtyMileF

def thirtyFiveMileC(wciC, t):

    wciC = 13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(35, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(35, 0.16)
    
    return thirtyFiveMileC

def thirtyFiveMileF(wciF, t):
    
    wciF = 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(35, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(35, 0.16)
    print("At temperature [0].0F, and wind speed 35 mph, the windchill is: [1]".format(t, wciF))
    
    return thirtyFiveMileF

def fortyMileC(wciC, t):

    wciC = 13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(40, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(40, 0.16)
    
    return fortyMileC

def fortyMileF(wciF, t):
    
    wciF = 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(40, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(40, 0.16)
    print("At temperature [0].0F, and wind speed 40 mph, the windchill is: [1]".format(t, wciF))
    
    return fortyMileF

def fortyFiveMileC(wciC, t):

    wciC = 13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(45, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(45, 0.16)
    
    return fortyFiveMileC

def fortyFiveMileF(wciF, t):
    
    wciF = 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(45, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(45, 0.16)
    print("At temperature [0].0F, and wind speed 45 mph, the windchill is: [1]".format(t, wciF))
    
    return fortyFiveMileF

def fiftyMileC(wciC, t):

    wciC = 13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(50, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(50, 0.16)
    
    return fiftyMileC

def fiftyMileF(wciF, t):
    
    wciF = 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(50, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(50, 0.16)
    print("At temperature [0].0F, and wind speed 50 mph, the windchill is: [1]".format(t, wciF))
    
    return fiftyMileF

def fiftyFiveMileC(wciC, t):

    wciC = 13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(55, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(55, 0.16)
    
    return fiftyFiveMileC

def fiftyFiveMileF(wciF, t):
    
    wciF = 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(55, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(55, 0.16)
    print("At temperature [0].0F, and wind speed 55 mph, the windchill is: [1]".format(t, wciF))
    
    return fiftyMileF

def sixtyMileC(wciC, t):

    wciC = 13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(60, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(60, 0.16)
    
    return sixtyMileC

def sixtyMileF(wciF, t):
    
    wciF = 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(60, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(60, 0.16)
    print("At temperature [0].0F, and wind speed 60 mph, the windchill is: [1]".format(t, wciF))
    
    return fiftyMileF

if degree == "F":
    fiveMileF(wciF, t)
    tenMileF(wciF, t)
    fifteenMileF(wciF, t)
    twentyMileF(wciF, t)
    twentyFiveMileF(wciF, t)
    thirtyMileF(wciF, t)
    thirtyFiveMileF(wciF, t)
    fortyMileF(wciF, t)
    fortyFiveMileF(wciF, t)
    fiftyMileF(wciF, t)
    fiftyFiveMileF(wciF, t)
    sixtyMileF(wciF, t)
    
elif degree == "C":
    fiveMileC(wciC, t)
    tenMileC(wciC, t)
    fifteenMileC(wciC, t)
    twentyMileC(wciC, t)
    twentyFiveMileC(wciC, t)
    thirtyMileC(wciC, t)
    thirtyFiveMileC(wciC, t)
    fortyMileC(wciC, t)
    fortyFiveMileC(wciC, t)
    fiftyMileC(wciC, t)
    fiftyFiveMileC(wciC, t)
    sixtyMileC(wciC, t)
```

I want it to run the equation in each individual function and then print it but for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong with the code, if anyone could help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You are returning values that does not exists

Comment: Is there a reason you need 24 functions?  Seems this could be done with one.  Also, why are you returning the name of the function rather than the computed value?

Comment: How would you recommend I go about doing that? Obviously I don't want to make more work for myself but this was the only way I could think of, and to address your second comment I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's becuase you're not using the correct symbols.
For string.format(), the placeholders should be inside curly brackets ({ and }), not square brackets ([ and ]). So for example in your fiveMileC function, it should be `print("At temperature {0}.0C, and wind speed 5 mph, the windchill is: {1}".format(t, wciC))`.
I'd reccomend just using Ctrl-H to fix this, it's a pretty simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions don't return the actual value they're computing, they try to return themselves (which doesn't work because they haven't been defined yet).

As one of the comments pointed out, you don't need to copy+paste all these different functions.  Just have one that takes all the parameters for the calculation, and then use a `range` to call it for each of the desired wind speeds.

```
from enum import Enum


class TempScale(Enum):
    F = "F"  # Fahrenheit
    C = "C"  # Celsius


def wind_chill(t: float, scale: TempScale, wind_speed: float) -> float:
    return (
        13.12
        + 0.6215 * t
        - 11.37 * wind_speed ** 0.16
        + 0.3965 * t * wind_speed ** 0.16
    ) if scale == TempScale.C else (
        35.74
        + 0.6215 * t
        - 35.75 * 5 ** 0.16
        + 0.4275 * t * 5 ** 0.16
    )


t = float(input("What is the temperature?: "))
degree = TempScale(input("Fahrenheit or Celsius? Please put F or C: "))

for speed in range(5, 61, 5):
    print(
        f"At temperature {t}{degree.value}, "
        f"and wind speed {speed} mph, "
        f"the windchill is: {wind_chill(t, degree, speed)}"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your functions are:

- Your input parameters wciC and wciF is incorrect (you can't update values this way in Python as you can in other languages where parameters are passed by reference)
- You are returning the name of the function (which I'm not sure why)

Rather than 24 functions, you can recode as singe function as follows.

**Code**

```
import math

def calc_windchill(speed, t, deg):
  ' windchill based upon speed, temperature and deg (F or C) '
  if deg == "F":
    return 35.74 + 0.6215*t -  35.75*math.pow(speed, 0.16) + 0.4275*t*math.pow(speed, 0.16)
  else:
    13.12 + 0.6215*t -  11.37*math.pow(speed, 0.16) + 0.3965*t*math.pow(speed, 0.16)
```

**Usage--Create Result from 5 to 65 mph**

```
t = float(input("What is the temperature?: "))
degree = input("Fahrenheit or celsius? Please put F or C: ")

for speed in range(5, 65, 5):
  print(f'Speed {speed}, Windchill {calc_windchill(speed, t, degree)}')
```

**Input**

```
What is the temperature?: 70
Fahrenheit or celsius? Please put F or C: F
```

**Output**

```
Speed 5, Windchill 71.70916934582954
Speed 10, Windchill 70.82531333540499
Speed 15, Windchill 70.26098370128452
Speed 20, Windchill 69.83779238304979
Speed 25, Windchill 69.49585945951326
Speed 30, Windchill 69.20727414121399
Speed 35, Windchill 68.95662425691367
Speed 40, Windchill 68.73444792440651
Speed 45, Windchill 68.5344954040776
Speed 50, Windchill 68.3524106668557
Speed 55, Windchill 68.1850297182379
Speed 60, Windchill 68.02997800248346
```